# CSS bottom Property problem on small screen

Tags: html, css

This is the css. The problem is when the screen is in `1366x768`, div didn't stick with the bottom `navbar`.

Is there any other ways that can replace the bottom property?

```css
.Newmealpopout {
  position: fixed;
  left: inherit;
  bottom: 56px;
  height: 220px;
  padding: 6px;
  background-color: #9e9e9e;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-3 mts-padding-all-15 mts-border-right text-center" style="">
  <span style="margin-left:-3px; color: black!important;  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px ;">Meal</span> &nbsp;<a href="javascript:$(&#39;#pnlmealNew&#39;).slideToggle(&#39;fast&#39;);" onclick="fntToggleHotelList(event);" class="meal-toggle tourdetail-ttp mts-hypl mts-text-12"
    data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="View Meals"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-info-circle"></i></a>
  <br>

  <div class="row">
    <div id="pnlmealNew" class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-3  Newmealpopout mts-padding-top-10 mts-padding-side-10" style="display: none;">
    </div>
  </div>
```

you can refer the screenshot for references

[image]

Comment: Please create a [mcve] demonstrating your issue - with the information and code provided it is impossible to say what your problem is

Comment: Hi, maybe on smaller resolutions your bottom navbar has different (smaller) height? As in comment above, we need a sample from u.